# Make the navigation bar stay on top of any activity animation

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

First of all I'm working with the Android-L preview. Now, For anyone to not to misunderstand what navigation bar is, here's a pic of it:
https://imageshack.com/i/f0bjjDnQp

I'm applying the activity animation that follows:

```
activity.startActivity(intent);
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.scale_in);
```

Where R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"/>
</set>
```

and R.anim.scale_in is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.9"
        android:toYScale="0.9"/>

    <alpha
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.1"/>
</set>
```

The animation works fine except for the fact that the new activity does the animation on top of the navigation bar, I'd like it to be the opposite. Also I can see the black status bar during the whole animation which I would like to avoid too.

**UPDATE:**

So I found what the problem is. With the introduction of Android L preview we have the option to set this Material theme, and that theme makes the animations between activities this way. If I set android:Theme.Holo.Light for instance, everything works fine. As soon as I add this Material theme I got this ugly effect of overlaying the Navigation Bar.
So I thought I could try to find the right parameter in the Material Theme to make it behave as the old theme but I can't manage to figure it out. I've tried setting this line below, but it doesn't work either.

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay" >false</item>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

Comment: The attribute you've found is about ActionBar, and I think it's false by default anyway. Have you found the solution to this issue?

Comment: I haven't found the solution, I found what I thought it was the problem as I mention in my UPDATE section. @androiddeveloper

Comment: @Dlleixap That's the thing. the attribute you've found doesn't help... Anyway, I've posted about this issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2947